# ASP.NET Return image from .aspx link

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to output an image (or any file type) to a download link when a user clicks on a link from another ASP.NET page?

I have the file name and byte[].

```
<a href="getfile.aspx?id=1">Get File</a>
```

...where getfile returns the file instead of going to the getfile.aspx page.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would want [.ashx for that](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/) really ;)

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler 
{ 
  public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } } 

  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx) 
  { 
    var myImage = GetImageSomeHow();
    ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/png"; 
    ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(myImage); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: .aspx would go through the page life cycle. .ashx is better here because there is no need for that, so probably performs better. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469491/aspx-vs-ashx-main-difference

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I have done this in the past:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename=\"{0}.pdf\"",Guid.NewGuid()));
Response.ContentType = @"application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(path);
```

Comment: Having a space between "inline;" and "filename" seemed to matter on my server

Answer (score 5):

[How to Create Text Image on the fly with ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/createTextImage.aspx)

Something like this:

```
string Path = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "\image.jpg");
Bitmap bmp = CreateThumbnail(Path,Size,Size);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
bmp.Save(Response.OutputStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: ashx is most of the time what you want BUT sometime you really need a aspx page for instance if you using the MapPageRoute that doesn't accept an ashx.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you have to clear the response completely and replace it with the image byte data as a string, and you need to make sure to set the response header for content-type according to the type of image

Comment: What if I do not have the content type?

Comment: Infer it from the file extension.  That's all the OS is doing anyway (change a jpg extension to a gif and ask any built-in function or utility what type of file it is).

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type you should use  "application/octet-stream" for an unknown content-type. But if your sending an image to be shown in the page then the browser will have to know the content-type and you have to do what @Rich says. But the octet-stream content type will work if your only what to save the file as the browser doesn't care about what it is.

Answer (score 0):

the codebehind code for getfile.aspx has to have a [content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) and the browser will know that it is an image or a unknown file and will let you save it.

In asp.net you can set the [ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208.aspx) by using the [Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525405.aspx) object, i.e.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/GIF"
```

[Here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/generating-asp-net-images-fly) you have a tutorial for dynamically generated image

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  There are two parts of the Response object you need to set: the Content-Type and the HTTP Header.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx) has the details on the response object but the main concept is pretty simple.  Just set the code to something like this (for a Word doc).

```
Response.ContentType="application/ms-word";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=download.doc");
```

There is a more complete example [here](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Code-Examples/File-download-using-C/)

Answer (score 0):

ashx...

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
       string path = ".....jpg";

                byte[] imgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                if (imgBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    ctx.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                    ctx.Response.BinaryWrite(imgBytes);
                }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get {return false;}
    }
}
```