# .aspx vs .ashx MAIN difference

Tags: asp.net, service, ashx

What are the differences between .aspx and .ashx pages? 
I use ashx now when I need to handle a request that was called from code and returned with a response, but I would like a more technical answer please.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`Page` is a special case handler.

Generic Web handler (`*.ashx`, extension based processor) is the default HTTP handler for all Web handlers that do not have a UI and that include the `@WebHandler` directive.

ASP.NET page handler (`*.aspx`) is the default HTTP handler for all ASP.NET pages.

Among the built-in HTTP handlers there are also Web service handler (`*.asmx`) and Trace handler (`trace.axd`)

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx):

> An ASP.NET HTTP handler is the process
>   (frequently referred to as the
>   "endpoint") that runs in response to a
>   request made to an ASP.NET Web
>   application. The most common handler
>   is an ASP.NET page handler that
>   processes .aspx files. When users
>   request an .aspx file, the request is
>   processed by the page through the page
>   handler.

The image below illustrates this:
[image: request pipe line]

As to your second question:

> Does ashx handle more connections than aspx?

Don't think so (but for sure, at least not less than).

Comment: thank you, but you didnt mention the ashx handler, what about its Request Pipe Line ?

Comment: @Arrabi, `HttpHandler` is just a *section* of the request which is being executed before `Page` section.

Answer (score 88):

`.aspx` uses a full lifecycle (`Init`, `Load`, `PreRender`) and can respond to button clicks etc.
An `.ashx` has just a single `ProcessRequest` method.

Comment: What is meant by 'reusable' in this context?

Comment: That the web server is not obligated to create a new object instance per new request. If IsReusable=true on the Handler, then the server may reuse existing handler objects to process next requests

Comment: So it creates an instance of handler and keeps in the memory to reuse it. It never give it back to GC.

Answer (score 29):

.aspx is a rendered page. If you need a view, use an .aspx page.
If all you need is backend functionality but will be staying on the same view, use an .ashx page.

Comment: that I know, I wanted more technical answer maybe with numbers, does ashx handle more connection than aspx ?

Answer (score 3):

For folks that have programmed in nodeJs before, particularly using expressJS. I think of `.ashx` as a *middleware* that calls the `next` function. While `.aspx` will be the *controller* that actually responds to the request either around `res.redirect`, `res.send` or whatever.