# Why the .aspx inherited IDispose,but .ashx not?

Tags: asp.net

They are all inherited the Interface IHttpHandler,so the asp.net will call they by the same way. But why the aspx page inherited IDispose? Asp.net is how to achieve it?

Comment: Read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469491/aspx-vs-ashx-main-difference

Comment: I am so sorry that this question can not solve my problem.The application call the factory (PageHandlerFactory or SimpleHandlerFactory) to make IHttphandler,and process they by the same way(not use "using").So why the aspx page inherited the IDispose

Comment: aspx has (supposed to have) UI controls. StakcOverflow is more about fixing programming problems faced during development. If you have very specific product related query, you better ask the vendor, in this case Microsoft. I mean, if you have a implementation problem regarding aspx having IDispose or ashx not having it, then describe the problem. We shall show you a workaround or solution to that problem. But if you need to know why, better ask the team in Microsoft

Comment: No matter how thank you anyway~

Comment: And my workaround is about "have a implementation problem regarding aspx having IDispose or ashx not having it". I only what to understand the deep reason. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET **page** is inheriting from the base `System.Web.UI.Page` class which in turn implements the abstract `System.Web.UI.TemplateControl` class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Control` *which implements `IDisposable`*.

In the code, there is the remark for the `Dispose()` of the Control class:

```
// Summary:
//     Enables a server control to perform final clean up before it is released
//     from memory.
```

That's the reason why `.aspx` file essentially implements the `IDisposable` interface.

Now, ASP.NET **handler** is directly implementing the `System.Web.IHttpHandler` interface without inheriting any other classes - being independent interface, it does not implement `IDisposable` - it's up to the programmer to decide whether to add such thing or not.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is, how does the `Dispose()` code of the aspx (`Page`) ever get called?

You're making the assumption that ASP.NET framework only sees an `IHttpHandler`, whether it contains a `Page` or another implementation. That's almost certainly not true; *something* needs to call the page's constructor.

You could use a tool like [IL Spy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to try to find where the different handling is, and what it looks like.