# How can I extract certificates contained in an ashx file with openssl?

Tags: openssl, x509, pem, der

in a SCEP process I'm developing, the first step has to be this one ([link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security-vpn/public-key-infrastructure-pki/116167-technote-scep-00.html))

> **1. CA Authentication**
>
> SCEP uses the CA certificate in order to secure the
>   message exchange for the CSR. As a result, it is necessary to obtain a
>   copy of the CA certificate. The GetCACert operation is used.
>
> **1.1 Request**
>
> The request is sent as a HTTP GET request. A packet capture for the
>   request looks similar to this: GET
>
> /cgi-bin/pkiclient.exe?operation=GetCACert

So, after sending the request I get back a ashx file which contains three X.509 certificates in some kind of binary data.

[image: Response succeed]

> Success - The request is accepted and the signed certificate is
>   included. The signed certificate is held within a special type of
>   PKCS#7 called a "Degenerate Certificates-Only PKCS#7," which is a
>   special container that can hold one or more X.509 or CRLs, but does
>   not contain a signed or encrypted data payload.

Is there any way I can extract those three certificates using openssl? Because I'm not finding out how. I would like to extract them in a pem or der format. Thanks in advance

PS: I'm quite new with all these enviromments.

Comment: ASHX is just an ASP HTTP handler. It like saying, [*"I got a HTTP file"*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5469491). You need to fully describe what you really have.... You might start with Microsoft's [Network Device Enrollment Service (NDES)](https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+ndes) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I need to learn a lot of stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

So, a colleague found a solution.

The CA certificate is requested to an URL like these one:

```
http://myserver.com/MyIDSCEP/MyIDSCEP.ashx
```

and what gives you back is a file like this one

```
CERTIFICATES.ashx
```

Where are three certificates contained. If you execute this you can get them:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform der -in test.der -print_certs
```

This my problem was solved. Thanks.