# How to use graphviz into asp.net core mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, graphviz

I had searched over internet to find out the library which is support for graphviz in asp.net core. There is a library called [Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper](https://github.com/Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper) which is used GraphViz but not support asp.net core. Is there any way to use graphviz into asp.net core mvc?

Comment: When you say ".NET Core" do you really mean cross platform, or do you only care about Windows? If the later, you could still give the library a try.

Comment: I have already integrate the https://github.com/Rubjerg/Graphviz.NetWrapper this one into my project and working fine in local machine but when deploy into IIS server then the c++ dll dependency is not working

Answer (score 1):

Normally, .NET graphics toolkits write their result to the local screen.

But it can be done.

Link the toolkit in a separate DLL, do your thing.. And instead of updating a screen, convert the result of your graphics to a server side *image file*. Then pass a link to the new image file to the caller via ASP.NET

You don't even need to create a file,

[ASP.NET Return image from .aspx link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253228/asp-net-return-image-from-aspx-link)

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Works nicely if you don't have too much traffic - however you judge or measure that ;-)

Comment: You'll be surprised.. you can't handle thousands of clients with a setup like that, but when modern graphics tools write to an in-memory bitmap instead of the screen, it will be ready asap. You do not need to write a physical file, with ASP.Net it is possible to return the image in the request. An alternative would be to let the browser do all the painting, maybe your library can draw to an .svg file ?

Comment: I added a link to another StackOverflow topic that touches the subject.